# How to conform the ButtonStyle protocol in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'd like to create a custom button in SwiftUI that I want to reuse throughout the app. The button is basically just a clickable image with no label on it.
I thought about creating a custom ButtonStyle for it.
Though, I have problems conforming the ButtonStyle protocol as don't know which type I should choose here.

I already tried `some View` or just `View` for `<#type>` but that didn't work out.

```
struct customButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    typealias Body = <#type>
}
```

The error messages I get when trying to use `View` or `some View` is:
 `Type 'customButtonStyle' does not conform to protocol 'ButtonStyle'` and XCode just adds this line `typealias Body = <#type>` again.

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You define custom style in `makeBody` function. You can use `configuration.isPressed` to configure the button in a slightly different way when it's pressed.

```
struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            // all of the modifiers you want to apply in your custom style e.g.:
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? .red : .blue)
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems custom ButtonStyle didn't work on iOS 15 anymore.

Comment: ButtonStyle still works until now. Also, 'func makeBody' is a must to conform to protocol 'ButtonStyle'.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a custom style for a button, this is one way to do it working with SwiftUI 3 and Swift 5.5:

Create your styles:

```
extension View {
    // Theme 1
    func theme1ButtonStyle() -> some View {
        self.modifier(Theme1ButtonStyle())
    }
    // Theme 2
    func themeBlueButtonStyle() -> some View {
        self.modifier(ThemeBlueButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

The modifiers of each style (I'll write only 1, you get the idea):

```
struct ThemeBlueButtonStyle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}
```

You can call it like:

```
Text("SIGN UP")
    .themeBlueButtonStyle()
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like in iOS 15, the ButtonStyle protocol is gone, so you cannot do this. Instead, you have to accept the list of pre-made button styles, and the only way to customize is through ViewModifiers...
I couldn't find anything about it in the Apple documentation :(